# Reading a plist

Tags: macos, cocoa, plist

I'm trying to read ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist (on Snow Leopard) to get the email address and other information to enter into the about dialog. I'm using the following code, which is obviously wrong:

```
NSBundle* bundle;
bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *plistData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSString *item = [plistData valueForKeyPath:@"MailAccounts.Item 2.AccountName"];    


NSLog(@"Result = %@", item);
```

Moreover, the value I need to read is `MailAcounts -> Item 2 -> AccountName` and I am not sure I am doing this correctly (due to the space in the `Item 2` key).

I tried reading Apple's developer guide to plist files but no help there.

How can I read a plist and extract the values as an NSString?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first level is an array, so you need to use `"MailAccounts.AccountName"` and treat it as `NSArray*`:

```
NSString *plistPath = [@"~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
NSDictionary *plistData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSArray *item = [plistData valueForKeyPath:@"MailAccounts.AccountName"];
NSLog(@"Account: %@", [item objectAtIndex:2]);
```

Alternatively you can go by keys and pull the array from `"MailAccounts"` first using `valueForKey:` (which will yield `NSArray*`) and then `objectAtIndex:` to get the dictionary of that particular account (useful if you need more than the name).

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You don't want or need to use `NSBundle` to get the path to the file. The file lies outside of the app bundle. So you should just have

   ```
   NSString *plistPath = @"~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist";
   ```
2. You have to expand the tilde in the path to the user directory. `NSString` has a method for this. Use something like

   ```
   NSString *plistPath = [@"~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
   ```

Comment: OK, still. All I get is a NULL value out.

Comment: Alright, got it to read from the property list by just `"MailAccounts.AccountName"` instead of `"MailAccounts.Item 2.AccountName"`. The only problem is that there is `Item 0` and `Item 1` as well under MailAccounts. They are null so the reading now returns an NSString as {null, null, email@email.com}.